# Is this translucent blue ramp-like brick from an old Space Explorer set?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, space

Is this brick from an old Space Explorer set? I cannot seem to find a number on it. Any help to link this brick to a particular LEGO set would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It's older than that.

[This element](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4228&name=Slope,%20Inverted%2033%205%20x%206%20x%202&category=%5BSlope,%20Inverted%5D#T=C) has been in 9 sets, in trans-dark blue (as pictured) it has been in 4:
https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4228&colorID=14&in=A
that bricklink says came out in 1981 and 1983

Comment: Technically it only appeared in 3 sets, the 4th listing is an “extra” for one of the first 3 sets.

Comment: That is one **big** extra.

Comment: @PhilB. To be fair it appears in all 4 sets. The last one doesn't use it to build main model however, but is required to build a "super model". This "super model" is using elements from two more sets: 6880 and 6929, according to Brickset.

Comment: Thank you so much for such swift replies. It is very kind. I had my first space explorer set in the early 1980s and managed to mix up all the bricks.    
I think it is an “extra” for the 4th space set as I don’t recall building the other sets (and don’t have a box or instructions for the others).
Thanks all once again!

Comment: @Valky Glad that you found the answer helpful, could you please make this official by accepting it through clicking on the checkmark icon on the left side?

Comment: @Alex I stand corrected :)

Comment: @zovits have done now thanks. First time I have used a forum in this (quite sensible) format. Best wishes to all.

Comment: @Valky Thanks, and welcome to this community! Feel free to read the [help] and take the [tour] to learn more if you are interested in what makes this format sensible :)